# URL aliases problem when assigning aliases for custom pages

Tags: path-aliases, 7

I have created some content type page around 10 pages after that I started creating custom page like **page-node-11.tpl.php**. I want to assign node number 11 to my newly created page but when a assign node/11 it will give me error msg

The path `node/11` is either invalid or you do not have access to it

How to overcome this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it in reverse order. This order is generally followed.
Create a page.
Note down the node number (ex : 7) 
Then create a file corresponding to that like page-node-7.tpl.php
You should not assign node/11 as alias as these are considered as internal paths.
You can give anyother name which mostly suits the page contents.

Comment: but its working if i create page-node-3.tpl.php and asign node/5 or node/6

Comment: node/11 etc are internal paths , if you are entering these paths as alias it will conflict for some existing nodes, which could be the reason for getting invalid message. Alias are usually meant to give meaningfull names such as "AboutUs" , this makes better sense than node/11 and still you can theme this page using page-node-11

Comment: Thanx kantu... now im clear in assigning node aliases<br> it solves my problem.